# Is this the best time to apply for US visas?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, nigerian-citizens

At this point of my life I am very confused.
I have travel history for about 6 West African nations, and 2 East African nations (Rwanda and Ethiopia).

Is this a good time to apply for US visas?

Comment: When do you plan to travel? There is still a world wide crisis and travel will not really open up for a while yet.

Comment: @Willeke , um say August, Although i am still touring Africa for now.... :)

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? Is your question aimed at understanding if a travel history limited to African nations is of any value when applying for a US visa? Or are you interested in the impact of Covid on visa applications?

Answer (score 12):

> Is this a good time to apply for US visas?

No. We are in the middle of a world wide pandemic with severe travel restrictions and most embassies & consulates are either closed or working with significantly reduced capacity. This is actually a terrible time to apply for a visa and you should only consider this if you have an urgent travel need.

See https://ng.usembassy.gov/visas/

Comment: "with severe travel restrictions" There are no entry restrictions for foreigners visiting the US by air, as long as they have not been to Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, Brazil, or South Africa in the preceding 14 days.